# SSRS - how to create a double entry table

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2012

I need to create a report which is something similar to a Pivot Table.

The report would be something like below, with more towns

```
           I  C  S  Total
Town1      1  2  3  6
Town2      7  1  1  9  
Town3      2  3  1  6
Total     10  6  5  21
```

In Crystal reports, there is an integrated function called `Cross table`

(see pictures below)

[image]

I'm looking for a similar function in SSRS, if there is any. I parsed the internet but I could not find anything that is relevant

Thanks!

Comment: In SSRS it is called a matrix, share a sample of your dataset if you need further help.

Comment: Hi @alejandrozuleta, I tweek a bit ssrs and it is working fine now. Thank. I will delete my question as it is of no use. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @alejandrozuleta, thinking about it as I solved my problem , thanks to you. It is also an opportunity in helping ppl who are looking for something similar so here is my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `matrix` to do so

Select the row, once the matrix created, like the image below and click on the `row group` and look at the `group properties`

[image]

You then choose the row for which you want to do the grouping like the image below

[image]

> Repeat the operations for the column group.

You will need to add additional row and columns for the total.

I will do that for the row. You click the row to highlight it and then click on `insert rows`. You then choose `Outside group below` like in the picture below

[image]

> Repeat the operations for the column group.

To have total, please put the following formula in your row and column created outside of the group `SUM(COUNT(Fields!name_of_your_field.Value))` and you have the double entry table.

Let me know through the comments if you have any issues, I'll happy to help.